# How can I restore full farm backup from one machine to another in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, backup, restore

We have SharePoint 2013 site in Customer environment and want to have one copy of this site in our server in our company.

First I get full farm backup from this machine from central admin.
After I restore this backup using central admin in my new machine every thing is OK but site is not shown when I type its URL. Settings and Viewlists are as mentioned before.

I can restore site collection in this farm but can't restore full farm 
Any Idea?

Comment: Are there any custom solution need to re-provision/deploy ?

Comment: any change on AAM or IIS Binding ?

Comment: When i try to build my customize login page in sharepoint it gives me 
Error occurred in deployment step 'Recycle IIS Application Pool': Cannot connect to the SharePoint site: http://Vm-sharepoint/. Make sure that this is a valid URL and the SharePoint site is running on the local computer. If you moved this project to a new computer or if the URL of the SharePoint site has changed since you created the project, update the Site URL property of the project.

Comment: mahdi. Supposed that your previous farm name server1, and then you take the backup. then you restore to where ? Still server1 or you restore to another server, e.g server2

Comment: only get full farm backup from customer site and restore from backup from central admin and tick all option and RESTORE –

Comment: I have just back from my holiday, how is this so far ?

Comment: Hey, have a nice day, i cant restore farm but when i restore site collection it works fine. I dont know what should i do

Comment: to answer your last comment , i change name of the farm, domain name is different too, and server name is different. maybe because of this.

Comment: I can't conclude the reason why, hehe :D